# Implement For Loop with Counter

Tags: vba, for-loop, counter, ms-word

I have a Word Userform where I add text boxes dynamically. The code then puts information from the textboxes to bookmarks which are picture filenames. It is all dynamic in that you enter how many textboxes you need and it then adds them to the userform and the text in the document. I left this last part of code out because its very long and not needed at this point.

I am attempting to put this first part of my code into a "For Loop" but I have been having a lot of difficulty doing so. The second part of my code I am providing has a textbox counter I trying to tie into it.

Right now my code works if I enter 10 into a textbox called "Amount" which you see throughout the code. I need to be able to enter any number.

If you think the entire code will help let me know and I will add it instead. I have been able to get everything else to work but for some reason this has had me stumped for days.

**Need "For loop" implemented**

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

Dim Textbox As Object
Dim Textbox1 As Object
Dim Textbox2 As Object
Dim Textbox3 As Object
Dim Textbox4 As Object
Dim Textbox5 As Object
Dim Textbox6 As Object
Dim Textbox7 As Object
Dim Textbox8 As Object
Dim Textbox9 As Object
Dim Textbox10 As Object    

Dim TBs(9) As Object
Set TBs(0) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_1"): Set TBs(1) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_2"): Set TBs(2) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_3")
Set TBs(3) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_4"): Set TBs(4) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_5"): Set TBs(5) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_6")
Set TBs(6) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_7"): Set TBs(7) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_8"): Set TBs(8) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_9")
Set TBs(9) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_10"):

Dim i
For i = 0 To Amount - 1
    With ActiveDocument
        If .Bookmarks("href" & i + 1).Range = ".jpg" Then
            .Bookmarks("href" & i + 1).Range _
            .InsertBefore TBs(i)
            .Bookmarks("src" & i + 1).Range _
            .InsertBefore TBs(i)
            .Bookmarks("alt" & i + 1).Range _
            .InsertBefore TBs(i)
      End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

**TextBox Counter**

```
Private Sub AddLine_Click()    

Dim theTextbox As Object
Dim textboxCounter As Long

For textboxCounter = 1 To Amount
    Set theTextbox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Test" & textboxCounter, True)
    With theTextbox
        .Name = "TextBox_" & textboxCounter
        .Width = 200
        .Left = 70
        .Top = 30 * textboxCounter
    End With

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "Right now my code works if I enter 10 into .." What happens if you enter 9?  (You could put the controls into an array as you create them; without a name)